# InvalidInputException When loading file into Hbase MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am very new for Hadoop and Map Reduce. For starting bases i executed Word Count Program. It executed well but when i try running csv file into Htable which i followed [Csv File][1]
It throwing me in to following error which i am not aware of it, please can any one help me in knowing the above error

```
    12/09/07 05:47:31 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hduser cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path   [1]: http://salsahpc.indiana.edu/ScienceCloud/hbase_hands_on_1.htm#shell_exercises
```

This error is really kiiling my time, please can any one help me with this exception

Comment: Can you post your Java code and the command you've used to start the Map/Reduce job?  It looks like you're not configuring the InputFormat correctly.

Comment: HI, Please check the post i have updated my code and command which i have used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem why you are directing to path hdfs://HadoopMaster:54310/user/hduser/csvtable instead of csvtable is.
1) Add your Hbase jars into Hadoop class path because your Map reduce doesn't  by default configure to hbase jars.
2) GO to hadoop-ev.sh and edit Hadoop_classpath and add all your hbase jars in it. hope it might work now

Answer (score 0):

your job is attempting to read an input file from:

```
 hdfs://HadoopMaster:54310/user/hduser/csvtable
```

you should verify that this file exists on HDFS using the hadoop [shell tools](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.19.0/hdfs_shell.html#ls):

```
hadoop fs -ls /user/hduser/csvtable
```

my guess is that your file hasn't been loaded onto HDFS.

Comment: Based on the linked article, it looks like `csvtable` is meant to be interpreted as an HBase table name rather than an HDFS file.  `input.csv` looks to be the input HDFS file.

Comment: HI matt, Your are right its a hbase table, i am trying to load data from file to hbase table "csvtable". But hear its looking for file rather than table. To solve this issue what i need to do next.

Comment: Hi paul,"csvtable " is not a file, its a table name, its reading as file.Its not reading as HTable Name

Comment: Hi my issue got solved, it with classpath settings. Hbase is not by default avaliable for hadoop. i seted the hadoop-classpath for hbase. my issue got resolved